# Did pkill -u root on working server. What should I do?

Tags: linux, root, kill

I accidentally did `pkill -u root` on a working Linux server. None of the root processes is working right now. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Reboot. It'll be quicker than trying to restart processes individually by hand.

Comment: I've added an answer so that, if you wish, you can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reboot. It'll be quicker than trying to restart processes individually by hand.